# Can Dataflow sideInput be updated per window by reading a gcs bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I’m currently creating a PCollectionView by reading filtering information from a gcs bucket and passing it as side input to different stages of my pipeline in order to filter the output.  If the file in the gcs bucket changes, I want the currently running pipeline to use this new filter info.  Is there a way to update this PCollectionView on each new window of data if my filter changes?  I thought I could do it in a startBundle but I can’t figure out how or if it’s possible.  Could you give an example if it is possible.

```java
PCollectionView<Map<String, TagObject>> 
    tagMapView =
        pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.named("TagListTextRead")
                                  .from("gs://tag-list-bucket/tag-list.json"))
                .apply(ParDo.named("TagsToTagMap").of(new Tags.BuildTagListMapFn()))
                .apply("MakeTagMapView", View.asSingleton());
PCollection<String> 
    windowedData =
        pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic("myTopic"))
                .apply(Window.<String>into(
                              SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(15))
                                            .every(Duration.standardSeconds(31))));
PCollection<MY_DATA> 
    lineData = windowedData
        .apply(ParDo.named("ExtractJsonObject")
            .withSideInputs(tagMapView)
            .of(new ExtractJsonObjectFn()));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want something like "use an at most a 1-minute-old version of the filter as a side input" (since in theory the file can change frequently, unpredictably, and independently from your pipeline - so there's no way really to completely synchronize changes of the file with the behavior of the pipeline).

Here's a (granted, rather clumsy) solution I was able to come up with. It relies on the fact that side inputs are implicitly also keyed by window. In this solution we're going to create a side input windowed into 1-minute fixed windows, where each window will contain a single value of the tag map, derived from the filter file as-of some moment inside that window.

```
PCollection<Long> ticks = p
  // Produce 1 "tick" per second
  .apply(CountingInput.unbounded().withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
  // Window the ticks into 1-minute windows
  .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
  // Use an arbitrary per-window combiner to reduce to 1 element per window
  .apply(Count.globally());

// Produce a collection of tag maps, 1 per each 1-minute window
PCollectionView<TagMap> tagMapView = ticks
  .apply(MapElements.via((Long ignored) -> {
    ... manually read the json file as a TagMap ...
  }))
  .apply(View.asSingleton());
```

This pattern (joining against slowly changing external data as a side input) is coming up repeatedly, and the solution I'm proposing here is far from perfect, I wish we had better support for this in the programming model. I've filed a [BEAM JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1197) to track this.

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution but I can't get the correct syntax for filling in from 'ignored'.  I'm not sure what MapElements.via wants.  Can you please fill that in a bit more precisely.

Comment: It's a Java 8 lambda, but indeed I got the syntax wrong. Make sure you're using Java 8 - otherwise, use a regular ParDo and an anonymous class.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the answer above. The Count.globally() requires GlobalWindow execution which means that it can't particularly be used with streaming dataflows. Is there a part which is missing here?

Comment: Count.globally() does not require a global window - Count generally operates per-window.

Comment: That's odd, I tried multiple combinations of it but they all fail with "Default values are not supported in Combine.globally() if the output PCollection is not windowed by GlobalWindows." Is this behaviour runner specific in any way? I am using DirectPipelineRunner for testing this.

Comment: Added test code segment: https://gist.github.com/ankurcha/c0719d9caa7cda1dbfce0bb696187a66

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad - the error message explains my error: global combining (including global counting) generally doesn't require global windows, but if you request to produce a default value for an empty input PCollection (rather than an empty result PCollection), then it does - and Count.globally() by default requests that. Try Count.globally().withoutDefaults()?

Comment: ah! i see, I did the changes and provided a default pcollection but it looks like DirectRunner doesn't like that "no evaluator registered for Read(UnboundedCountingSource)". Is that the correct way to handle the lack of default (i.e. startup)

Comment: It seems you're using Dataflow SDK (as opposed to Apache Beam - the two will be unified in the near future, and Beam will be the only SDK). The message says DirectRunner does not support CountingInput.unbounded() - in the Dataflow SDK, it indeed does not: there is no support for in-memory streaming pipelines. However: 1) if you want to keep using Dataflow SDK, you can use the service runner DataflowRunner 2) you can also switch to Beam SDK (it should be painless - they diverged rather little) and use InMemoryRunner, which supports streaming pipelines too.

Comment: Is beam + google cloud dataflow service ready for usage in production workloads? Any known issues especially with streaming jobs?

Comment: People are already successfully using Beam + Dataflow in production, but indeed that's not yet formally the recommended configuration (it is our highest priority to make it the case). See https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/08/cloud-dataflow-apache-beam-and-you . I don't know of a public list of known issues for running Beam on Dataflow - I think the main issue would be that Beam API is simply not declared stable yet, unlike Dataflow SDKs.

Comment: Took me a while to grasp the idea that the "tick" is just a way to trigger the manual data "injection" per window. I was trying to use this method instead of trying to get the previous window data in other ways. While I was able to write to datastore as an output, reading from datastore "manually" became a problem. I will appreciate any clarification.

Comment: you need to add withoutDefaults, see documentation: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Combine

Comment: It looks like the `CountingInput` no longer exists. (I'm using Beam SDK 2.6)

Comment: It's called GenerateSequence now.